# I got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

Making request from @vue/cli 4.5.8 app to my laravel ( Laravel Framework 8.24.0 with
hosting http://local-backend-currencies.com )
backendpoint app  I got error in the console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://local-backend-currencies.com/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

On client part :

```
console.log('+login settingCredentialsConfig::')
console.log(settingCredentialsConfig)

axios.post(apiUrl + '/login', userCredentials, settingCredentialsConfig)
  .then((response) => {
```

settingCredentialsConfig is defined :

```
export const settingCredentialsConfig = {
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    // Authorization: -1
  }
}
```

and in src/main.js :

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.crossDomain = true
```

and on laravel part in composer.json:

```
"license": "MIT",
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0",
},
```

In config/auth.php :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

],
```

In app/Http/Kernel.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,  // I ADDED THIS LINE
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,


        'jwt.auth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken', // I ADDED THIS LINE
        'jwt.refresh' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken'   // I ADDED THIS LINE
    ];
}
```

In config/cors.php :

```
<?php

return [


    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],


    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I cleared cahce and dumped composer.

What did I miss ?

Thanks!

Comment: `Access-Control-*` headers are response headers. Your server sents them. In your php config file, you limit them to url that start with `/api` by specifying the `paths`. But you are trying to request a url that does not have that /api pattern.

Comment: it looks like your `apiUrl` need to be different when you in `development` env.  you solve this checking the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable

Comment: Where have I to set that /api pattern ?

Comment: Yes, I lost "/api" in url of http://local-backend-currencies.com/api in my .env.production. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It is because you want to access a remote location `http://local-backend-currencies.com` from your localhost via JS - and this is prohibited.

To call the `login` you should call `http://localhost:8080/login`. I tink you call the Laravel backend  from your local development env `localhost:8080` - which is a bad idea.

I am unsure how CORS is set up in your application, what package you use for it, but if really everything is ok you should allow `localhost:8080`. If you use Laravel 7+ see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#cors) about this.

Comment: no, all sites including ttp://local-backend-currencies.com are on 1 local system under apache 2

Comment: But the request is coming from `http://localhost:8080`. It clearly says it in the error message you posted.

Comment: That is type of application with @vue/cli 4.5.8 as frontend and laravel  as backpointend

Answer (score -1):

One easiest way to do this is by adding this code to the beginning of your API route file (api.php)

```
//header parameters to allow external server to access
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With');
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into similar issues (I had set everything correctly in the cors.php file) and in my case, the fix was as follows:

0. Before anything else, rung: `php artisan optimize`
1. I had dd() in my code which was breaking the Middleware flow.

   Ref: [If you echo(), dd(), die(), exit(), dump() etc in your code, you will break the Middleware flow.](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#echodie)

2. Another case: My bootstrap/cache folder didn't have proper permissions. I updated permission to 775 which fixed the issue for me.

   `chmod 775 bootstrap/cache -R`

   `php artisan optimize`
3. Also, I made sure that there is no additional `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` present in the .htaccess file.